# Jenkins Pipeline "node inside stage" vs "stage inside node"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

As both `node` step and `stage` step provide scoped `{}` syntax, what is the best practice for defining their topology inside groovy code?

***Exhibit A***

```
node ("NodeName") {
    stage ("a stage inside node"){
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

***Exhibit B***

```
stage ("a stage holding a node") {
    node ("NodeName"){
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends on your actual needs.

As long as you can run your complete pipeline on a single node, I would wrap the `stage`s in a `node` so that the pipeline is not blocked by busy executors.

As soon as you use the `parallel` step, then you don't really have a choice besides having `stage` around `node` allocations.

There are (at least for me) no issues around mixing that, i.e., have the first 2-3 stages executed on the same node and then one stage that executes on multiple nodes within `parallel`.

Comment: That's interesting. I am having 5 stages inside a single node. I need to have the final stage on a different node (but not as parallel).

Comment: So where do you see the problem?

Comment: No problem... Just a remark.... That i might not really need the "parallel" step at all.

Comment: Yes, since 1.2 (Sep 2017), it's possible to have parallel stages: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Answer (score 13):

With `node { stage { ... } }`  each stage will share the same working folder and all the files from the previous stage will be there for the next stage.

With `stage { node { ... } }` you need to `stash`/`unstash` files between each stage. If you have a large repository, and especially if you have a large folder of dependencies like `node_modules`, this repeated `stash`/`unstash` could end up being a significant, or even majority, or your build time.

IMO I would generally start with the first syntax, `node { stage { ... } }` as preferred. If you have individual build stages that take time and can benefit from parallelism, then switching to `stage { node { ... } }` might be better, as long as the time gained in parallelization is not lost in stashing.

Update:

I tested the exact effect of swapping nesting on one of our builds. with a bunch of stages inside a node, the total build time is just over one minute. With a node inside each stage, total build time is almost five minutes. Big difference.

[image: Build stage timing example]

Comment: great stuff... thanks for sharing your findings. And the matter of stash / unstash is very helpful here :)

Comment: This is great example/explanation. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. In case of node { stage { ... } }, we are sure that stages will be executed by the same executor as well on the same node? If we have a node with 10 executors and sequential stages inside a node.

Comment: @Minee Sorry, I can't say. I haven't used Jenkins in a few years now. I'd suggest posting a new and you can reference this one for background. Good luck. 

Comment: @SamuelNeff According to Jenkins webpage the node keyword reserves an executor: "For more advanced usage with Scripted Pipeline, the example above node is a crucial first step as it allocates an executor and workspace for the Pipeline"